# java - Refreshing JComboBox throws exception

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jcombobox

I have a combobox using a model with a listener attached to catch the selected item:

```
deleteCombo = new JComboBox<Course>(course.toArray(new Course[course.size()]));
model = new DefaultComboBoxModel<Course>( course.toArray(new Course[course.size()]) );
deleteCombo.setModel( model );
deleteCombo.setRenderer(renderer);
deleteCombo.setSelectedIndex(0);
deleteCombo.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        JComboBox deleteCombo = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
        Course course = (Course)deleteCombo.getSelectedItem();
        deleteNumTxt.setText( course.getCourseNum() ); //This is line 391
        deleteTitleTxt.setText( course.getCourseTitle() );
        deleteDurationTxt.setText( String.valueOf(course.getDuration() ) );
        deleteFeeTxt.setText("$" + String.valueOf(course.getCourseFee() ) );
        deleteLevelTxt.setText( course.getCourseLevel() );
    }
});
```

I'm using the itemSelected event to populate textfields in the GUI to show the details of the course selected. When the course is selected and the Delete Course button is clicked it goes to this method:

```
public static void deleteCourseRecord() {
courseNumIn = deleteNumTxt.getText();
int index = course.indexOf(new Course(courseNumIn));
course.remove(index);

//RE-POPULATE EDIT AND DELETE COMBOBOXES
model.removeAllElements();
for(Course item : course) {
    model.addElement(item);
    }
}
```

The record gets deleted but it throws this exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at MyCourse$2.actionPerformed(MyCourse.java:391)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.fireActionEvent(JComboBox.java:1260)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.contentsChanged(JComboBox.java:1331)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.intervalRemoved(JComboBox.java:1351)
at javax.swing.AbstractListModel.fireIntervalRemoved(AbstractListModel.java:179)
at javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel.removeAllElements(DefaultComboBoxModel.java:175)
at MyCourse$Course.deleteCourseRecord(MyCourse.java:1138)
at MyCourse.actionPerformed(MyCourse.java:883)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
tjavax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
```

I think there is a problem in the way I've got the actionPerformed section constructed, but I don't know what it is. If I don't refresh the combo box with the model (or any other method) it doesn't throw the exception.If I comment out line 391 (marked in the code) it will throw the exception on line 392 and so on. If all the lines of code that are populating the textfields are commented out it throws no exception but, of course, the function is lost. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Cheers

Comment: which line is line 391

Comment: deleteNumTxt.setText( course.getCourseNum() ); //This is line 391

Comment: then either deleteNumTxt or course isn't instantiated. Where is deleteNumTxt set? From the code you posted it looks like it is null

Comment: Where is `course` defined?

Comment: Sorry, I only posted the parts I thought were relevant. It is set many lines above the combobox. When I don't use any means of refreshing the combo box, the code works, but it causes other problems eg in the edit function.

Comment: @Spud Why `JComboBox deleteCombo = (JComboBox)e.getSource();` inside `actionListener`? You already have `deleteCombo` defined. If you delete that line, I think you will be good.

Comment: @Egar Boda it is the arraylist being used to hold the objects. As I mentioned, it seems to be the use of any means of refreshing the combo box that causes the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is as follows:

Everytime you change the model that is set to the combo box the action listener is called.

So when you do this:

```
//RE-POPULATE EDIT AND DELETE COMBOBOXES
model.removeAllElements();
```

The actionlistener is executed and

```
Course course = (Course)deleteCombo.getSelectedItem();
```

is null, since you just removed all elements from your combobox.

You can see this if you try this simple example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
    String [] s = {"1", "2"};
    DefaultComboBoxModel<String> model = new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>(s);
    JComboBox<String> j = new JComboBox<String>(s);
    j.setModel(model);

    j.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            System.out.println(((JComboBox) arg0.getSource()).getSelectedItem());               
        }
    });

    JFrame jf = new JFrame();
    jf.add(j);
    jf.setVisible(true);
    jf.setSize(100, 100);

    model.removeAllElements();
}
```

It will output `null`.

Comment: I tried your example and you are correct and it makes sense now that you have explained it. I thought the for loop would take care of it because it rebuilds the combo box, doesn't it? Is there a work around for this? Thanks

Comment: You could have a boolean class attribute `removing` that you set to true before you do your operations on the model. In the actionlistener you would then check `removing`, only executing the listeners code if `removing` is false.